# Teclado abre quando chamo meu LoginActivity, como solucionar isso?

Tags: java, android, xml

Teclado abre quando chamo meu LoginActivity, como solucionar isso?

Esse e meu LoginActivity.java

```
package fabiohcnobre.jhotelcolonialdosnobres;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS;

/**
 * A login screen that offers login via email/password.
 */
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    /**
     * Id to identity READ_CONTACTS permission request.
     */
    private static final int REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 0;

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    /**
     * Keep track of the login task to ensure we can cancel it if requested.
     */
    // UI references.
    private AutoCompleteTextView mEmailView;
    private EditText mPasswordView;
    private View mProgressView;
    private View mLoginFormView;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private String TAG;

    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    CallbackManager mCallbackManager;

    private GoogleApiClient client;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        // Set up the login form.
        mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
        signInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());


        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.sign_in_button:
                        showProgress(true);
                       signIn();
                        break;
                    // ...
                }
            }

            private void signIn() {
                Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
                startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);

            }


        });

        populateAutoComplete();

           mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
           mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }
                // ...
            }
        };


        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

        mCallbackManager  = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                showProgress(true);
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
                handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel");
                // ...
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error);
                // ...
            }
        });
        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.button_facebook_login);
        loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                showProgress(true);
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
                handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel");
                // ...
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error);
                // ...
            }
        });



        mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        mPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (id == R.id.login || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                    attemptLogin();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        Button mEmailSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
        mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                attemptLogin();
            }
        });

        mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
        mProgressView = findViewById(R.id.login_progress);
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    private void populateAutoComplete() {
        if (!mayRequestContacts()) {
            return;
        }

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    private boolean mayRequestContacts() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            return true;
        }
        if (checkSelfPermission(READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        }
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(READ_CONTACTS)) {
            Snackbar.make(mEmailView, R.string.permission_rationale, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setAction(android.R.string.ok, new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
            if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                populateAutoComplete();
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Attempts to sign in or register the account specified by the login form.
     * If there are form errors (invalid email, missing fields, etc.), the
     * errors are presented and no actual login attempt is made.
     */
    private void attemptLogin() {
        // Reset errors.
        mEmailView.setError(null);
        mPasswordView.setError(null);

        // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
        String email = mEmailView.getText().toString();
        String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

        boolean cancel = false;
        View focusView = null;

        // Check for a valid password, if the user entered one.
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(password) && !isPasswordValid(password)) {
            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
            focusView = mPasswordView;
            cancel = true;
        }

        // Check for a valid email address.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
            focusView = mEmailView;
            cancel = true;
        } else if (!isEmailValid(email)) {
            mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
            focusView = mEmailView;
            cancel = true;
        }

        if (cancel) {
            // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
            // form field with an error.
            focusView.requestFocus();
        } else {
            // Show a progress spinner, and kick off a background task to
            // perform the user login attempt.
            showProgress(true);
            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail", task.getException());
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                showProgress(false);
                            } else {
                                Intent it = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, searchActivity.class);
                                startActivity(it);
                            }
                        }
                    });

        }
    }

    private boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
        //TODO: Replace this with your own logic
        return email.contains("@");
    }

    private boolean isPasswordValid(String password) {
        //TODO: Replace this with your own logic
        return password.length() > 4;
    }

    /**
     * Shows the progress UI and hides the login form.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
    private void showProgress(final boolean show) {
        // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
        // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
        // the progress spinner.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
            int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

            mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            mLoginFormView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                    show ? 0 : 1).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });

            mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            mProgressView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                    show ? 1 : 0).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                }
            });
        } else {
            // The ViewPropertyAnimator APIs are not available, so simply show
            // and hide the relevant UI components.
            mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        return new CursorLoader(this,
                // Retrieve data rows for the device user's 'profile' contact.
                Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI,
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY), ProfileQuery.PROJECTION,

                // Select only email addresses.
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE +
                        " = ?", new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email
                .CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE},

                // Show primary email addresses first. Note that there won't be
                // a primary email address if the user hasn't specified one.
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.IS_PRIMARY + " DESC");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
        List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            emails.add(cursor.getString(ProfileQuery.ADDRESS));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        addEmailsToAutoComplete(emails);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {

    }

    private void addEmailsToAutoComplete(List<String> emailAddressCollection) {
        //Create adapter to tell the AutoCompleteTextView what to show in its dropdown list.
      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<>(LoginActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, emailAddressCollection);

        mEmailView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    public Action getIndexApiAction() {
        Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
                .setName("Login Page") // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
                .setUrl(Uri.parse("http://[ENTER-YOUR-URL-HERE]"))
                .build();
        return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
                .setObject(object)
                .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }


    private interface ProfileQuery {
        String[] PROJECTION = {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.IS_PRIMARY,
        };

        int ADDRESS = 0;
        int IS_PRIMARY = 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();// ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
// See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, getIndexApiAction());
     //Login automatico com facebook
        //   LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();// ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
// See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, getIndexApiAction());
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        client.disconnect();
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Falha Google",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }else {
            mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
              .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                  @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Falha FireBase",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Intent it = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, searchActivity.class);
                            startActivity(it);
                        }

                    }
               });
    }

    private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);

        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else {
                            Intent it = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, searchActivity.class);
                            startActivity(it);
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

Esse meu activity_login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="fabiohcnobre.jhotelcolonialdosnobres.LoginActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="461dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <!-- Login progress -->
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/login_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView2" />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/login_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/email"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:singleLine="true" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/password"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                        android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                        android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                        android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:singleLine="true" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
                    style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/button_facebook_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
            android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É necessário modificar a propriedade `android:windowSoftInputMode` da tua `activity`. É possível fazer isso no teu AndroidManifest da seguinte forma:

```
<activity android:name="fabiohcnobre.jhotelcolonialdosnobres.LoginActivity" 
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"  />
```

Você pode fazer isso para outras `activities` também.

Comment: Giuliana deu certinho obrigado